# C++ list iterator arithmetic

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, containers, arithmetic-expressions

I am aware that you cannot use iterators with list in the form "it +n" but why is that when I use ++it the program is able to compile i.e:

```
//program compiles
list<int> v {1,2,3,4}; 
auto begin = v.begin(),
end = v.end(); 
while (begin != end) {
    ++begin;  
    begin = v.insert(begin, 42); 
    ++begin;  // advance begin past the element we just added
}

//program doesn't compile
list<int> v{1,2,3,4}; 
auto begin = v.begin(),
end = v.end(); 
while (begin != end) {
    begin+=1; //or alternatively begin = begin +1 
    begin = v.insert(begin, 42);  // insert the new value
    ++begin;  // advance begin past the element we just added
}
```

Comment: Are you asking why the designers of the standard library chose to support `++begin` but not `begin += n`?

Comment: Possibly because `operator++` is overloaded.

Comment: Because that's the way `list`'s iterator (a `bidirectional_iterator`) is specified in the standard.   If you want to step by n, increment n times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to standart std::list implements bidirectional iterator http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/BidirectionalIterator/ that doesn't have "+=" operator

Comment: I've found charts like [this one](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/) showing iterator categories and the operators they support useful.